# How to adjust Script per tab sheets to Reset Entire Page and Reset Formulas and Dropboxes Only?

Tags: reset

everyone looking for a solution here with the GS I would like to adjust the script to apply to multiple sheets but become active on per active open tab sheet only.
In addition, is it possible to run a GS through merge cells?

Any assistance or suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

GS Script below:

```
    // This section adds the top menu
    function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Reset')
    .addItem("Formulas Only", "ResetFormulas")
    .addItem("Entire Page", "ResetPage")
    .addToUi()
    }
    // This section makes a button to reset the whole page copies the entire page
    function ResetPage() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Territory4');  // Enter tab name of what you’re copying from
    sheet.getRange('A1:S200').copyTo(ss.getRange('A1:S200')) //enter entire tab 
range
        }
        // This section copies only the cells you specify
        function ResetFormulas() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Territory4'); // Enter tab name here of what you’re copying from
        //Header
        sheet.getRange('C2:C4').copyTo(ss.getRange('C2:CC4')) //first range you’re copying
        sheet.getRange('G7:H200').copyTo(ss.getRange('G7:H200')) //next range
        sheet.getRange('J7:J200').copyTo(ss.getRange('J7:J200')) //etc
        sheet.getRange('L7:L200').copyTo(ss.getRange('L7:L200')) //you get it
        }
```